# getExternalFilesDir permissions

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

My application is live on Play Store, I noticed that I was not asking permissions when calling:

```
File savedImagesDirectory = getBaseContext.getExternalFilesDir("SavedImages");
if(savedImagesDirectory != null) {
    if (!savedImagesDirectory.exists()) {
        if (savedImagesDirectory.mkdir()) ; //directory is created;
    }
}
```

Strange thing is, I'm not getting any crashes when calling this without runtime permissions. I tested on my device running Nougat and the files are created and I experienced no crashes.

I only have permissions in my Manifest, but I don't ask runtime permissions.

I've seen A LOT of answers on SO that say that runtime permissions should be asked when creating a folder/file in external file directory.

---

**My question:**

Should I ask runtime permissions when calling the above? If yes, why am I not experiencing any crashes?

It would also be helpful if someone can provide a link where I can read up about this.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although it returns path to external storage, you don't need permission to access directory returned by `getExternalFilesDir()`.

It is same as `getFilesDir()` but it is public to other apps as well.

Also note that if you write anything in that directory and clear app data or uninstall the app, everything will be deleted.

For more information, read the documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDir(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

not need ask runtime permission, but if your app's minSdkVersion less then 19 and you need write to getExternalFilesDir() path , you need declare WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your AndroidManifest.xml

check this :https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score -4):

```
String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
requestPermissions(permissions, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

use this code

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] 
grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
   case WRITE_REQUEST_CODE:
     if(grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
       //Granted.


     }
   else{
       //Denied.
     }
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but this doesn't answer my question. I know how to ask for permissions, but that was not my question.