# android: EACCS permission denied when using context.getExternalFilesDir

Tags: android, android-file

Im basically trying to download a file from an url.So i decided to store in my app file.So
I used **getExternalFilesDir**, so that i don't require any permission pop up as per these links:

[Do I need runtime permission check to write into getExternalFilesDir() path in marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34469395/do-i-need-runtime-permission-check-to-write-into-getexternalfilesdir-path-in-m)

[getExternalFilesDir permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52437112/getexternalfilesdir-permissions)

[The Death of External Storage: The End of the Saga(?)](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html)

However, **it works on android 8.0, but on my Letv Le 1s Marshmellow device without storage permission, it doesn't work!**

Below is my code:

```
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(urlString))
            return;
        URL u = new URL(urlString);
        is = u.openStream();
        dis = new DataInputStream(is);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        File storageDir = new File(getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).toString(), "downloads/");
        String fileNameFromUrl = urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf("/")+1,urlString.length());
        String ext = urlString.substring(urlString.lastIndexOf(".") + 1, urlString.length());
        storageDir.mkdirs(); // make sure you call mkdirs() and not mkdir()
        File downloadPath = new File(storageDir + File.separator +  fileNameFromUrl);
        if(downloadPath.exists()){
            downloadPath.delete();
        }
        downloadPath.createNewFile();
```

downloadPath is **/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example/files/Movies/downloads/file.mp4**

This line downloadPath.createNewFile(), throws **java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES(Permission denied)**

My idea is to use the application's directory for reading and writing files for in-app uses and not to ask for storage permissions.So I used context.getExternalFilesDir.

I have explored many SOF links as mentioned above, but it didn't help me solve the issue!

Comment: Does `storageDir' exist?

Comment: use  context.filesDir() instead

Comment: @blackapps: I have checked all the times:  storageDIrs always exists: moreover i give  storageDir.mkdirs() also

Comment: @FahadAlotaibi May  i know the difference between getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesdir()?

Comment: read this for more info, https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage

Comment: `over i give storageDir.mkdirs() also – `. You are not checking the return value of mkdirs(). Check it! And dont call mkdirs if the directory already exists.

Comment: It is pretty strange that you can create directories like 'Movies/downloads' but not a file in it.

Comment: `downloadPath.delete();`. Check the return value and handle accordingly.

Comment: storageDir.mkdirs() returns me false, when i dont give storage permission explicitly, but it gives me true when i give the permission..but in my android 8.0 device, it works without any explicit permission given!!